# Use references from attached DLL file

Tags: c#, dll, reference

I have created a DLL that contains the reference to Microsoft.Azure.Devices (and some other references).
I'd like to be able to just use this DLL in other projects without the need to reference Microsoft.Azure.Devices each time. Is it possible?

Currently, in order to use any function of Microsoft.Azure.Devices I have to reference it in my new project, which isn't a good solution I think - I'd like my DLL to be a "complete" reference - I just want to use the abstraction layer that I created without caring what is inside (what references are used).

Comment: So you would like your consumers of your assembly to only use your assembly instead of referencing the Microsoft DLL as well?

Comment: You would still need to put the Microsoft.Azure.Deveice dll into the bin folder of your library.  detape solution would build a new library that contains your code and the Azure code in a single executable.

Comment: **The dependencies of your dependencies are your dependencies too**. If your DLL exposes any public type on *Microsoft.Azure.Deveice* you need a direct reference, but if your DLL encapsulates everything then you don't need the reference (but still need the library's binary accesible as *jdweng* said).

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like you want to use some kind of DLL weaving. That will merge all external referenced assemblies and your assembly into a new one.

There are multiple frameworks to achieve this. I personally have used these two:

- IL Merge
- Costura Fody

From a usage point of view fody was very easy to use. You basically reference it using Nuget (see https://www.nuget.org/packages/Costura.Fody/) That's pretty much it. It will pack all your references into one assembly.
You can find more information on the Git page https://github.com/Fody/Costura

The only limitation of this approach is that you can not use that with signed assemblies I think.